# add button to page with chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

is it possible to add simple button with onclick event to a page with chrome extension?

for instance if I am looking at

> google.com

```
var google = document.getElementById("main");
    var button = document.createElement("button");
    var text = document.createTextNode("test");
    button.appendChild(text);
    google.appendChild(button);
```

I see my button in it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use that code in a [`content script`](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/mv3/content_scripts/) set to run on specific webpages.

> Content scripts are JavaScript files that run **in the context of web
> pages**. By using the standard Document Object Model (DOM), they can
> read details of the web pages the browser visits, or make changes to
> them.